# Can't make retrofit and Gson pull data from deployd

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I am very new to Android development. I have this little project of mine that I need to get to work by accessing an api that I created locally on my mac with deployd. The api is accessible from localhost:2403/subjects. I have followed the retrofit and gson guide but so far I only keep errors and nothing viable to work with. At this point im kinda stuck. I need to get the subjects from the api and show them in a scrollable list.

I have set up Retrofit and Gson to be able to talk to the API. Therefore I have made a few classes and interfaces.

First the Subject class

```
public class Subject {

    int id;
    String name;
    int ects;
    int grade;
    int period;
    int main;

    public int getMain() {
        return main;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getEcts() {
        return ects;
    }

    public int getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public int getPeriod() {
        return period;
    }

}
```

then I created a HslSubjects class which is plain and simple to hold all the subjects I get.

```
public class HslSubjects {
    List<Subject> subjects;
}
```

and the api interface

```
public interface subjectEndpointApi {
    @GET("/subjects")
    Call<HslSubjects> loadSubjects();
}
```

followed by an adapter

```
public class SubjectResponse {

    @SerializedName("subjects")
    List<Subject> subjects;

    public SubjectResponse() {
        subjects = new ArrayList<Subject>();
    }

    public static SubjectResponse parseJSON(String response) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        SubjectResponse subjectResponse = gson.fromJson(response,    SubjectResponse.class);
        return subjectResponse;
    }
}
```

Finally in my mainActivity I run everything

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements Callback<HslSubjects> {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        ArrayAdapter<Subject> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Subject>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, new ArrayList<Subject>());
        setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        setProgressBarVisibility(true);

        Log.i("api", "preparing to make the api call");
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://10.0.3.2:2403") //10.0.3.2
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        // preparing the call in retrofit
        subjectEndpointApi subjectEndpointApi = retrofit.create(subjectEndpointApi.class);
        Call<HslSubjects> call = subjectEndpointApi.loadSubjects();

        call.enqueue(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<HslSubjects> call, Response<HslSubjects> response) {
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        HslSubjects hslSubjects = response.body();

        Log.i("subjects", "end of response");


    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<HslSubjects> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Log.i("subjects", "Oops error");
    }
}
```

But somehow it always goes to the onFailure class. The emulator gives the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your server JSON is not what you are expecting on your device. 
Error says that android wants JSON **object**, but the json you pass is kinda **array**.

Try to add logging and see what is the problem there.

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
```

So I guess you should write something like:

```
public interface subjectEndpointApi {
    @GET("/subjects")
    Call<List<Subject>> loadSubjects();
}
```

Comment: but isn't that what I do in HslSubjects which I use in mainActivity as Call<HslSubjects> call = subjectEndpointApi.loadSubjects(); ?

Comment: The interceptor gives the following response: http://pastebin.com/raw/BKxV6inV so apparantly I do get the stuff from the api but it can't handle anything

Comment: see, you are receiving an array, but you asking for an object. Try to change you code my way

Comment: I have tried your way but its still triggering the onFailure method.